# Doctrine: UniqueEntity with Many-to-Many field

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I have a class Repair that should have unique entries for "name", "device", and "color". I.e. there should only be one "Replace screen" for "iPhone 5c" in colours "red" and "green".

However, Symfony throws an exception:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name
>   AS name_2, t0.minutes AS minutes_3, t0.safetytime AS safetytime_4,
>   t0.cost AS cost_5, t0.device_id AS device_id_6 FROM repair t0 WHERE
>   t0.name = ? AND t0.device_id = ? AND repairs_colors.color_id = ?' with
>   params ["Replace screen", 2, {}]:
>
> **Catchable Fatal Error**: Object of class
>   Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string

**Here is my Entity definition (Repair.php):**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="repair")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\RepairRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name", "device", "colors"}, message="There already exists a repair job with name {{ value }} for this device and these colours.")
 */
class Repair {

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Device", inversedBy="repairs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="device_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $device;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Color", inversedBy="repairs")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="repairs_colors",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="repair_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="color_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      ) 
     */
    private $colors;
}
```

I understand that Symfony is passing an empty array of colours instead of the actual colours set. But why?

Comment: May be you have missed to add `__toString` function in your `Color` entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Validator/Constraints/UniqueEntityValidator.php) is the source code of the UniqueEntity constraint in Symfony.

As default Symfony will internaly do a query like :

```
->findBy(array(
'name'=>$entity->getName(),
'device'=>$entity->getName(),
'colors'=>$entity->getColors() // <- Precisely here, doctrine is not able to traduce that in a SQL query.
));
```

**Workaround** : Create you own [Repository method](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#repositorymethod), and use it in your constraint :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="repair")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\RepairRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name", "device", "colors"}, repositoryMethod="getSimilarRepairs")
 */
class Repair {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Alsatian, you're the guy from the ExtensiveEntityBundle! Thanks, I use that! So I get what you mean and I'm trying to write my own DQL Repository code, without much succes at the moment. But I wonder why it fails at `getColors()`?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know exactly why it fails ;)