# Doctrine: Custom repository to determine UniqueEntity does not work

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

In order to solve a [problem I asked about earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655878/doctrine-uniqueentity-with-many-to-many-field), I am trying to create a custom repository function that will determine whether an instance of `Repair` is unique, based on the `device`, `name`, and `colors` constraints.

Here's my Doctrine Annotation for class `Repair`. Mind that the `device` property is Many To One (many Repairs for one Device), and that `colors` is Many to Many.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="repair")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\RepairRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name", "device", "colors"}, repositoryMethod="getSimilarRepairs", message="Repair {{ value }} already exists for this name, device and colour combination.")
 */
```

This is my **RepairRepository.php**, in which `$criteria['colors']` is an array.

```
public function getSimilarRepairs(array $criteria) {
    $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->where('r.device = :device')
        ->andWhere('r.colors = :colors')
        ->andWhere('r.name = :name')
        ->setParameters(['deviceid'=>$criteria['device'],'colors'=>$criteria['colors'],'name'=>$criteria['name']]);
    return $builder->getQuery();
}
```

I have three problems that can probably be brought back to one:

- editing: with every change, causing a duplicate or not, I get the message that a duplicate entity exists.
- editing: despite the error message, name changes are performed anyway!
- adding: I can create as many duplicates as I like, there never is an error message.

Comment: Do you see this post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148678/symfony-2-uniqueentity-repositorymethod-fails-on-update-entity

Comment: Yous custom query does the same as the default query. It is normal that it won't work :) I will give a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the colors relation is a ManyToMany.
In SQL you can not query '=' on this relation.

It is very complicated, that's why Doctrine (and we probably) can't make it alone .

A partial solution to build a query :

```
public function getSimilarRepairs(array $criteria) {
    $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->where('r.device = :device')
        ->andWhere('r.name = :name')->setParameter('name',$criteria['name'])
        ->andWhere('r.colors = :colors')->setParameter('deviceid',$criteria['device']);

    // r matches only if each of your colors exists are related to r :
    $i=0;
    foreach($criteria['colors'] as $color){
        $i++;
        $builder->join('r.colors','c'.$i)->andWhere('c = :color'.$i)->setParameter('color'.$i,$color);
    }

    // Then you had also to check than there is no other color related to r :

    // I don't know how


    return $builder->getQuery();
}
```

**But let me propose another solution :**

In your repair entity, your can store a duplicate of your related colours :

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name_canonical", type="string")
 */
private $serializedColors;
```

set it with doctrine lifecycle events :

```
/** 
* @ORM\PrePersist
* @ORM\PreUpdate 
*/
public function updateColors()
{
    $serializedColors = '';

    foreach($this->colors as $color){
        $serializedColors .= $color->getId().'#';
    }

    $this->serializedColors = $serializedColors;
}
```

Don't forget to add [@HasLifecycleCallbacks](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-haslifecyclecallbacks)

Then change your UniqueEntityConstraint to `fields={"name", "device", "serializedColors"}`, forget the custom query, and it will work.

Comment: That's a very interesting solution @Alsatian. Never thought about it that way. It does feel a bit 'dirty' though, saving data for the sheer purpose circumvening logic, but I assume it will increase performance. Thank you I'll try it out in a bit and report back soon.

Comment: YEs it is dirty, but I never found better for this usage.